# return node from networkx by node key?

Tags: python, networkx

I have reviewed the networkx documentation multiple times and I cannot find a way to return the node object based on the node key. The reason I need this is because I would like to use the node information to check both node properties and edge information (which requires the node key!)

For example:

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(
    [('vi|123', {
    'type': 't1',
    'name': 'vi'
    }), 
    ('vi_1|234', {
    'type': 't2',
    'name': 'vi_1'
    })]
)

edge_list = [
    ('vi|123', 'vi_1|234'),
]
g.add_edges_from(edge_list)
print(g.nodes(data=True)['vi|123'])
```

This will only print the node attributes without the node key. Is there any native way to achieve this? Otherwise the best I can think of is to duplicate the node key information in my node attribute.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code sample, I tried this:

```
print(g.nodes(data=True))
>> [('vi|123', {'type': 't1', 'name': 'vi'}), ('vi_1|234', {'type': 't2', 'name': 'vi_1'})]
```

When you call up the g.nodes as an iterator rather than on each individual node it seems you can get the node key/name. Perhaps for what you're trying to do you'll want to use this method to access node keys readily. Hope this helps!